# Google geocoding api OVER_QUERY_LIMIT occurs after 5 requests

Tags: ios, swift, google-api, geocoding

I have implemented the Geocoding api provided by google few months ago. I am currently facing a problem where I am only able to request 1-5 times per day and after that I get this error.

This is my request URL:
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?&latlng=12.9857325553894,77.5968754291534&sensor=false&key=API_KEY

`{
   "error_message" : "You have exceeded your daily request quota for this API.",
   "results" : [],
   "status" : "OVER_QUERY_LIMIT"
}`

I have even created new API keys but the result is same and the api key throws the same error after 1-5 request. I have disabled and enabled the API as well. The problem still exists.

Anybody know why this is hapenning?

Comment: are you actually replacing API_KEY with your actual API key

Comment: yes I am or else I wouldn't get the response at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

New accounts created get only 1 request per day for the Geocoding API.

I solved this problem by using the same API with the GooglePlacesSDK.